SharePoint site template with addContentTypesFromHub
I have created a site template (site design) having actions like addContentTypesFromHub (88 content type IDs), createSPList (47), addNavLink (54) etc. Total number of actions (verbs) count is 285. So I was expecting a single site script and design can be created.
When I try to create site script, I get error "Add-SPOSiteScript : This site script has exceeded the action limit of 30."

So I divided the addContentTypesFromHub actions to script1 and remaining actions to script2 which worked fine.
If I try apply the site design to a SharePoint site using (Add-SPOSiteDesignTask), its not working. I tried to check the status using PowerShell script: Get-SPOSiteDesignRun -WebUrl "SiteURL" but that doesn't return the status with the site design ID I have.
I created a separate site design with script having only addContentTypesFromHub action, and tried to apply this site design which worked fine.
I am suspecting that each site content type ID is being counted as an action, so even if I have only one addContentTypesFromHub action with 85 content type IDs, it is counting them as 85 actions. Which increases the total number of actions to more than 300 and then apply site design doesn't work. Is this true?

Yeah...
Things you could try:

AddSiteDesignTaskToCurrentWeb is the new REST endpoint for site designs (haven't tested it myself), try it instead of PnP
"createSiteColumnFromXml" rather than letting the "addContentTypesFromHub"
Check the sync list for errors on the trouble site at /Lists/ContentTypeSyncLog and also verify there are no columns with name conflicts anywhere, hidden or otherwise
have a look here: Cannot add content types from hub with Site Script and Invoke-SPOSiteDesign
Add-SPOSiteDesignTask should increase the limit to 100k, if it's not working, try your luck with Microsoft Support
Invoke-SPOSiteDesign was bumped to 300 actions - try that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-overview

